# How to acess swift 5 Result enum type in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift5

I have written a class method in swift-5 with it's parameter Result type, now I want to use this method in objective-c, is it possible? if yes, how?

```
@objc public class DemoClass :NSObject {

    @objc public func demoMethod(completion: @escaping (Result<UIImage,Error>) -> 
     Void) {
             //some codes
      }
}
```

As soon as I add @objc to method it throws an error: **Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C**

Comment: The error message should be pretty clear: "the type of the parameter (`Result<UIImage, Error>`) cannot be represented in Objective-C". So no, you can't access it from Objective-C, because it is not representable there. What you can do is, `(UIImage?, Error?) -> Void` like many Objective-C APIs do.

Comment: That is the last thing I'll do, initially, I wanted to if possible extend/inherit enum on the top of Result with minimal code, and then use this in swift and access in objective-c

Comment: You can't, that's a point I commented on a question (opinion based) asking if the author need to remove all its previous completion closure and replace them with Result. You can have a "legacy" method for Objective-C, but that will add you code, like one with a `(UIImage?, Error?) -> Void`, and calling internally the one with `Result`.

Answer (score 5):

The enum Result is inaccessible in Objective-C. It is `@frozen` and not `@inlinable`.

And also Objective-C enums cannot be generic, i.e., the `Result<Success, Failure> where Failure: Error` cannot to exposed to Objective-C.

So, what can you do is make a class as follows and do other stuffs as required:

```
@objc class AResult: NSObject {
    
    public private(set) var success: Any?
    public private(set) var failure: Error?
    
    private override init() {
        super.init()
        success = nil
        failure = nil
    }
    
    public convenience init<Success, Failure>(_ arg1: Success, _ arg2: Failure) where Failure: Error {
        self.init()
        success = arg1
        failure = arg2
        // Do something
    }
}
```

And declare your function: `@objc func demoMethod(_ completion: (AResult) -> Void) {}`

Hope this helps.