# Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 3 cannot be represented in Objective-C - Error type not recognized in @objc func?

Tags: swift, objective-c, async-await, objective-c-blocks

I’m trying to call this function from an objective C class but am running into an issue. I get the error "Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 3 cannot be represented in Objective-C"

I’m assuming the issue is with the “Error” parameter but don’t understand what the issue is exactly. Everything I’ve read has been dealing with Swift 1 or 2 but this is in Swift 5.

```
class NetworkManager {
    
    struct DataModel: Decodable {
        let id: String
        let carID: String
        let ownerId: String
        let locationId: String?
        let status: String
    }
    
    static let shared = NetworkManager()
    
    @objc static func fetchCarWarranty(for carID: String, ownerID: String, completed: @escaping (Result<[DataModel], Error>) -> Void) {
        
        let urlString = APIURL
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            if let _ = error {
                completed(.failure(error!))
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                completed(.failure(error!))
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let dataModel = try decoder.decode([DataModel].self, from: data)
                completed(Result.success(dataModel))
            } catch {
                completed(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I've thought of calling `fetchCarWarranty` from a second Swift function but not sure if this is a good practice to follow or not.

Also, how can I get the value from this function if I'm calling it from an objective-c file/ class?

Comment: You can't use `Result` in Objective-C, you need to use the old way. It could be two closure, one for success, and one for error, and a single one, with both values (and usually, one being nil). You can mark that method with `@objc` and let it call your Swift version with `Result`.

Comment: I think the issue is with the Result return in the callback. You can test by changing it to return just DataModel etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to acess swift 5 Result enum type in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576529/how-to-acess-swift-5-result-enum-type-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `Result` in Objective-C, you need a closure like the one for `dataTask(with:completion:)`, with optional parameters like `error` to indicate it's not in "error case":

```
//Call that one when using Objective-C
@objc static func fetchCarWarranty(for carID: String, ownerID: String, completed: @escaping (([DataModel]?, Error?) -> Void)) {
    fetchCarWarranty(for: carID, ownerID: ownerID) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let models):
            completed(models, nil)
        case .failure(let error):
            completed(nil, error)
        }
    }
}

//Call that one when using Swift
static func fetchCarWarranty(for carID: String, ownerID: String, completed: @escaping (Result<[DataModel], Error>) -> Void) {
    // Your method "Swifty" code
}
```

I did this for an app with legacy Objective-C code. You call in the end the Swifty method with `Result` internally. so the code does the same.

You could also for the Objective-C compatible one have to closures:

```
@objc static func fetchCarWarranty(for carID: String, ownerID: String, success: @escaping (([DataModel]) -> Void), failure: @escaping ((Error) -> Void)) {
    fetchCarWarranty(for: carID, ownerID: ownerID { result in 
        switch result {
            case .success(let models): 
                success(models)
            case .failure(let error):
                failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the issue is that `DataModel` is a `struct`. If you replace that with:

```
// With temp [String] parameter instead of [DataModel]
@objc static func fetchCarWarranty(for carID: String, ownerID: String, completed: @escaping (([String]?, Error?) -> Void)) {
    fetchCarWarranty(for: carID, ownerID: ownerID) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let models):
            completed(["models"], nil) //Fake output
        case .failure(let error):
            completed(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

It works, because `String` is visible by Objective-C. But you can't see a Swift struct from Objective-C. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes), or one the related questions:

[Is there a way to use Swift structs in Objective-C without making them Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845624/is-there-a-way-to-use-swift-structs-in-objective-c-without-making-them-classes)
[How to pass a Swift struct as a parameter to an Objective-C method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567380/how-to-pass-a-swift-struct-as-a-parameter-to-an-objective-c-method)
[How to use Swift struct in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173234/how-to-use-swift-struct-in-objective-c)

Comment: I'm getting many errors when attempting to implement this solution. Specifically the @objc func error still remains along with several other errors with the function.

Comment: When pasting your solution to test, it gives the exact same error OP posted about...

Comment: Is DataModel a class or a struct? I tested without compiler, I’ll check tomorrow

Comment: It's a struct. Thanks for your help

Comment: Then you can't as such. See my update answer.